# afnetworking multiple file upload

Tags: iphone, ios, file-upload, afnetworking

I am uploading multiple files using AFNetworking. 
I need to send extra information such as image width/height for each image.

I thought I would just loop through images and send them but AFNetworking doesn't quite handle it.
(I suspect AFNetworking combines multiple requests into one, overwriting extra informations)

Below is my code.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@URL_BASE];
int count = [imageArray count];

for(int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
 {
     UIImage* image = [imageArray objectAtIndex:i];
     AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];
     NSDictionary* params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                             [NSNumber numberWithFloat: image.size.width], @"width",
                                             [NSNumber numberWithFloat: image.size.height], @"height",
                                          nil];

     NSMutableURLRequest *request = [httpClient multipartFormRequestWithMethod:@"POST" path:@PATH_ALBUM_IMAGE_UPLOAD parameters:params constructingBodyWithBlock: ^(id <AFMultipartFormData>formData) {
             [formData appendPartWithFileData:imageData name:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"file%d", i]  fileName:@"avatar.jpg" mimeyTpe:@"image/jpeg"];
         }];

     AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
     [operation setUploadProgressBlock:^(NSInteger bytesWritten, long long totalBytesWritten, long long totalBytesExpectedToWrite) {

             [progressView setProgress: totalBytesWritten*1.0f / totalBytesExpectedToWrite animated: YES];
             NSLog(@"Sent %lld of %lld bytes", totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite);
             if(totalBytesWritten >= totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
             {
                 progressView.hidden = YES;
             }
         }];
     [operation start];
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turned out to be a known(but now fixed) bug of AFNetworking.

[AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/commit/782862b)

problem solved.

Comment: but if I use one **name** with multiple files, the last one will override the former. any suggestion ?